# Android:How to Avoid Activity being killed by System,ActivityManager: Process my package name (pid 935) has died

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, voip, aidl

I have a VOIP Based app which needs to be run 24/7..But System is Killing my application when my application is background..

1) How do i know when system is killing my application.?

2) Can i set some application parameter so that system wont kill my application.?

3) I am aware of how to re-storing the application when user clicks the app,but if system kill my app at 3 PM and if any data received at 3.30 PM will never reach my app as its killed by System.

4) Making Service based Design to my App will help?

How do over come this.i want to make my App Running all time and Listens to data from Server.

Your Comments will me much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your app designed ? Is the 24*7 process running as a Service in the background ? If not, I would suggest making it a Service, as, in that way, Android would only be killing it, in case, the phone memory goes too low (which is rare nowadays with lots of memory available at disposal).
If you can look for some broadcasts to be received (depending on what you are trying to do), you may set up a broadcast receiver and then invoke the service on broadcast receipt, else kill the service as well. That way, even the service won't be running all the time. 
So, it all depends, on what is your requirement..

Comment: Mark the answer as useful, if you really find it so :)

Comment: i have A Local Service Running Will that do??

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by local service ? I would suggest this approach. Broadcast receiver receiving broadcast from external entity, triggering the service in turn, which would do its action and then either stop itself / keep running if you MUST do that.. But pls bear in mind, that depending on the task hapenning within the service and keeping in really running 24*7 would also consume phone battery..

Comment: Android Local Service http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LocalService.html This is dummy service and is running all time to say system my application is doing some work.But My activity is acting as Receiver from server not Service.

Comment: Rather than having a dummy service to just let the android know, that the specific app is still running, let the service only do all the important work. You can create following components - Broadcast receiver (to receive your update broadcast assuming you have a push mechanism and not poll), a android service which would do all the main work (thus while service is running, android won't kill it (app)) and a activity to let the user know what's hapenning behind the scenes. So irrespective of whether the activity is in foreground / background, the service would stil do its work as you need.

Comment: Yeah exactly..But UI and Service interaction is bit tricky..My application init is done on launcher Activity OnCreate.. Now moving everything to service wil be a Huge design change is it not??

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. Yes, you need to make a service instead of an activity, which will not be killed by OS.

Comment: i have A Local Service Running Will that do??